# Resource Description on Web API Help page is showing "None."

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the Help page in my Web Api to show anything for Resource Description other than None. It has IHttpActionResult linked and then "None." after that. I got my samples working by adding `config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(ComplexType), "Controller", "Action");` to HelpPageConfig.cs. My controller looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// My description
/// </summary>
[Route("MyRoute")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        //throw new Exception("TEST");
        return Ok(returnValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        *Company Log Method*
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing from HelpPageConfig.cs or any place else. Maybe a fresh set of eyes can catch something. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just needed to add `[ResponseType(typeof(MyModel))]` above my action after including `using System.Web.Http.Description;` at the top of my controller. I'm getting the description of my model now instead of IHttpActionResult and "None."

Answer (score 0):

(This probably ought to be a comment but I don't have enough rep yet)

I'd start with break pointing the various points in Areas\HelpPage - e.g. XmlDocumentationProvider - to see if that gives you any clues. Nothing leaps out at me.

Could it be that you've changed where the XML help file is output and not updated the document path passed to XmlDocumentationProvider? The path is set through the Properties page - Output XML Documentation File.

Comment: Good advice for setting breakpoints, although I have no idea where to set them. As far as the XML file, the paths in HelpPageConfig.cs and in Properties are the same, and I've included it in the project, so it's not that.