# C# Web API Help Documentation IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I have a C# Web API and I am trying to get the auto created help documentation to work with IHttpActionResult. I stripped down the example below so its a little easier to read.

For the object, below is a simple example. BusinessObject is just a wrapper. The CollectionBase is `CollectionBase : ObservableCollection<T>, ILoadable where T : BusinessObject`. Its an older code base that is auto generated but reusing it for this.

```
    public class Value : BusinessObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Values : CollectionBase<Value>
    {
        public override Value LoadObject(System.Data.IDataRecord record)
        {
            return new Value();
        }
    }
```

For the API side of things. The following works.

```
public class Values : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Value> GetThis()
    {
        Values values = new Values();
        return values;
    }
}
```

[image]

The issue comes when I try to do

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetThis()
    {
        Values values = new Values();
        return Ok(values);
    }
```

It doesn't recognize that it should use a different return type. The 'Resource Description' ends up being IHttpActionResult with no sample output. Now I can add

```
config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Value>), "Values", "GetThis");
```

and it will show a sample output but the 'Resource Description' will still be IHttpActionResult. That is the main issue I am having. I would like to use IHttpActionResult because its very easy to use and can return error codes if needed very easily. I would just like to be able to auto construct the documentation.

**UPDATE**: Upon some further research, I did fine this post. 
[Resource Description on Web API Help page is showing "None."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722985/resource-description-on-web-api-help-page-is-showing-none)

Bascially, you add the response type attribute to the method.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Value>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetThis()
{
    Values values = new Values();
    return Ok(values);
}
```

Although this technically works and I have modified my existing code to use this. It would still be nice if there was a way to have it automatically figure it out somehow. Not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: You should probably answer your own question if you found out the answer (and yes, that is the correct answer ;P).

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about that. Was kind of hoping someone would come with a 'hey just change config to look at what the OK(type) returns' and it would do it for every method without having to include the attribute every time. I will leave it unanswered for a bit longer just to see.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This works for what I am doing. Its a little tedious to have to include every time but it allows me to return error codes if necessary and retain the help documentation functionality.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Value>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetThis()
{
    Values values = new Values();
    return Ok(values);
}
```

[Resource Description on Web API Help page is showing "None."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722985/resource-description-on-web-api-help-page-is-showing-none)